# How to retrieve an email from database where $_POST var is like username

Tags: php, sql, phpmailer, var

Here is the code

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['uuser'])){
       $gemail = mysql_result("SELECT `email` FROM `user` WHERE `username` LIKE '" . ($_POST['uuser']) . "';");

    $to ="$gemail"; // this is user's Email address 

    $from = "admin@mysite.com"; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['uuser'];
    $last_name = $_POST['uuser'];
    $subject = "Form submission";

    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
?>
```

The problem is with $gemail  its not getting email from database.

Comment: Echo $gemail and you will learn something very important :)

Comment: You need wildcards for `like` to work. You also are open to SQL injections, parameterize the query. Also shouldn't be using `mysql_` functions anymore.

Comment: Your SQL is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You should fix that. And you should not be using `mysql_result ` (it's deprecated) Your `$gemail` will always be empty because you are not connecting to a DB and you are not passing a DB resource to your `mysql_result`.

Comment: Also unrelated to your issue but `mail(` != `phpmailer`.

Comment: It also could be an issue that all your inputs seem to have the same name. e.g. email (username), firstname, and lastname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use mysql_query or mysqli_query. So below will be your code.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['uuser']);
$gemail = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `email` FROM `user` WHERE `username` LIKE '".$user."'");
```

Comment: Don't forget the `%`s.

Comment: Although OP isn't really specific as to how he wants to apply 'like', it's safe to assume that there must be some wildcards added to the like clause.